# CDT Eclipse: Undefined Variables even the .h file included

Tags: eclipse, stm32, eclipse-cdt, cortex-m

I'm newbie on using CDT and Eclipse. I want to make an STM32F10XX (Cortex-M3) aplication. I have a problem when I'm compiling the code, it always show undefined variables error. I used Eclipse setting as shown on Setting up Eclipse and Code Sourcery lite for STM32 Discovery Development.

But I make my own startup code, just using stm32_flash.ld and startup_stm32f10x_md_vl.S.

Is there any included or project setting missed?

discussionstackoverflowquestion

Answer (score 1):

Try using the gnu99 flavor of C.  Found in project Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings.  MCU C Compiler Miscellaneous.

I'm guessing it is complaining about an untagged union.  But this is a guess...